# Отображение числа набранных символов в textarea

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

У меня есть вот такая страничка html, также используется на ней jQuery. Как мне сделать так, чтобы в теге span с классом value отображалось динамическое число при вводе символов в поле textarea? (Т.е. 10...9...8..7..6 и так далее)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Textarea</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#comment").click(function(){
            $("#comment").fadeOut('slow');
            $('#commentDiv').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        var minLength = 10;
        var maxLength = 590;

        var current = $('#area').val().length;

        if(minLength - current != 0)
        {
            $('span.value') = minLength - current;
            $('span.second').hide();
            $('span.first').show();
        }

        if(minLength - current < 0)
        {
            $('span.value') = maxLength - current;
            $('span.second').show();
            $('span.first').hide();
            $(':submit').removeAttr("disabled");
        }

        if(maxLength - current == 0)
        {
            $('#area').keyup(function(){
                if(this.value.length > 600)
                {
                    this.value = this.value.substr(0,600);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="comment" class="btn btn-primary">Оставить комментарий</a>

    <div id="commentDiv" style="display:none;">
        <form>
            <textarea id="area"></textarea>
            <div id="info" style="float:right;">
                <span>
                    <span class="value">10</span>
                    <span class="first">символов нужно ввести</span>
                    <span class="second" style="display:none;">символов осталось ввести</span>
                </span>
                <input type="submit" value="Комментировать" disabled>
                <input type="reset" value="Сбросить">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сейчас в консоли Google Chrome показывает ошибку "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" в строке $('span.value') = minLength - current;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#comment").click(function(){
            $("#comment").fadeOut('slow');
            $('#commentDiv').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        var minLength = 10, maxLength = 590, current;
        $('#area').keyup(function(){
          current = this.value.length;
          if(current  > 600) {
            this.value = this.value.substr(0,600);
          }
          if(current < minLength) {
            $('span.value').html(minLength - current);
            $('span.second').hide();
            $('span.first').show();
          }else if(current > minLength ) {
            $('span.value').html(maxLength - current);
            $('span.second').show();
            $('span.first').hide();
            $(':submit').removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Обратите внимание, что вы не обрабатываете вариант когда ввели ровно столько символов сколько требуется в minLength. При 10 символах кнопка сабмита еще не разблокируется.
Если же это исправить - то вместо строки

```
}else if(current > minLength ) {
```

достаточно написать

```
} else {
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исчезла, но число в <span class="value"></span> не меняется динамически(

Comment: динамически не меняется потому, что вызывается код только 1 раз при загрузке.
В таком примере и ограничение в 600 символов работать не будет. Зачем вы все вынесли за пределы $('#area').keyup(function(){...});? Вся задумка в том, что бы проверки выполнялись при каждом нажатии клавиш в текстовом поле - внесите внутрь функции и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую переделать!

Comment: Изменил ответ - показал как может быть построен код. Проверьте возможно что-то пропустил :)

Comment: Дело в том, что количество символов не меняется( Показывает постоянно 10, и сколько символов я бы не ввел в поле textarea - все равно показывает 10!

Comment: Ну добавьте дэбаг в функцию $('#area').keyup(function(){...});
Поставьте какой-то alert и посмотрите вызывается ли вообще эта функция при наборе текста, можете заодно вывести информацию о "current" - какое значение символов она имеет при наборе текста. Найдите где ошибка и исправьте.